# sql delete with select conditional

Tags: php, mysql, select

maybe someone can help me.

I have 2 sql tables:

```
 // groups
 | id_group   | namegroup |
 +------------+-----------+
 | 30         | s         |


 // contacts
 | name | group |
 +------+-------+
 | juan | s     |
```

I need to DELETE a group from ID, but no has contacts associated with it.
I test the following query but doesnt work.

```
DELETE
FROM group
WHERE id_group = 30
AND (
    SELECT
        count(*) AS id
    FROM contacts co
    INNER JOIN GROUP c ON co. GROUP = c.namegroup
    WHERE   c.id_group = 30
) = 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to delete all groups which don't have any associated contacts? Or you just want to delete group having id = 30 only if it's not associated to any contact?

Comment: only group having id=30 only if its not associated to any contact.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query if you want to delete group having `ID = 30` only if the group is not associated to any contact :

**Query #1:**

```
DELETE
`groups`
FROM `groups`
LEFT JOIN contacts
ON contacts.`group` = `groups`.namegroup
WHERE `groups`.id_group = 30
AND contacts.`group` IS NULL;
```

And if you want to delete all groups which don't have any associated contact then try the following query instead:

**Query #2:**

```
 DELETE
 `groups`
 FROM `groups`
 LEFT JOIN contacts
 ON contacts.`group` = `groups`.namegroup
 WHERE contacts.`group` IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define firigen key mysql will handle this issue and you do not need to do anything

In these cases(without forigen key) i usually first run following query:

```
select count(*) as id from contacts co inner join group c on co.group=c.namegroup where c.id_group=30
```

And say to user which if they can delete or not and if he could delete that row:

```
delete from group where id_group=30
```

I tried to find a solution like query which you had but could not and suggest this solution for you.